# JQuery Texture Plugin?

Tags: jquery, textures

I'm working on an app where I would like a user to be able to choose a background texture for some text. I like how the JQuery Theme Roller allows you to choose a texture for things. Is there a JQuery plugin for choosing textures available anywhere? I've searched without any luck. I'm hoping someone knows more than me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you  looking for this  [Textures and colors](http://jquerydoodles.com/texture/)?

P.s : I did'nt try this.Just giving an hint to push you further.

Comment: I don't think it's exactly what he's looking for, but +1 for a great resource.